# How to do something after device unlocked on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've been searching a lot about this.

Is there a way, using only Flutter, to detect when the device is unlocked? (password, faceid, fingerprint, doesn't matter)...

For example, when the device is unlocked, I would like to open a Page/Screen/Activity.

Answer (score 0):

device unlocked not sure but thats going to cause you some problems with app stores

check [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)

In android  WorkManager is an API that makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts.It has contsraints.

Constraints ensure that work is deferred until optimal conditions are met. The following constraints are available to WorkManager.

- **NetworkType**  Constrains the type of network required for your work to
  run. For example, Wi-Fi (UNMETERED).
- **BatteryNotLow**     When set to true,
  your work will not run if the device is in low battery mode.
- **RequiresCharging**  When set to true, your work will only run when the
  device is charging.
- **DeviceIdle** When set to true, this requires the
  user’s device to be idle before the work will run. This can be useful
  for running batched operations that might otherwise have a negative
  performance impact on other apps running actively on the user’s
  device.
- **StorageNotLow**     When set to true, your work will not run if
  the user’s storage space on the device is too low.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and I will back here.